# Authenticate User manually

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to authenticate the user after I got credentials using oAuth (with Twitter if that makes a difference). As far as I could understand it, I can directly put the Authentication object into SecurityContextHolder. Here is how I do it:

```
Authentication auth = new TwitterOAuthAuthentication(member,
userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(member.getUsername()).getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```

This for some reason does absolutely nothing. What am I missing and what should I do to accomplish what need?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding

```
auth.setAuthenticated(true);
```

before you set the Authentication to the context.

The following code works fine for me (inside a filter class):

```
final Authentication auth = new CustomAuthenticationToken(user);
auth.setAuthenticated(true);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
```