# spring Authentication.setAuthenticated(boolean) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set this token to trusted

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have the following code (attempting to log a user in programatically):

```
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_ADMIN"));
...
User tempUser = new User(correctUsername, 
    correctPassword, 
    true, true, true, true, // logging them in...
    authorities // type is List<GrantedAuthority>
);
...
Authentication authentication 
    = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(tempUser, authorities);
    // I'm using authorities again (List<GrantedAuthority>)
    // is this the right spot for it?
...
// this is the line causing the error
authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
```

When I try to run that I get the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set this token to trusted - use constructor which takes a GrantedAuthority list instead
```

Note that I'm using the `authorities` list of `GrantedAuthority`s both in the [`User`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html) and [`Authentication`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) objects.  I'm not sure where I should be using those.  I'm trying to replicate the answer for [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466312/authenticate-user-manually) but am running into the exception posted above.  Other similar questions that didn't quite answer my question:

- [How to programmatically log user in with Spring Security 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614541/)
- [Programmatically login in a user using spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900994/)

After some searching the closest I've found to an answer was at [the forum at springsource.org](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?69761-User-registers-confirmation-email-account-activated-user-logged-in-automatically), and that person's using a [deprecated method](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html#User%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority%5B%5D%29), but it's a similar approach.  How can I log a user in programatically?

Comment: Which line is causing the problem?

Comment: the last one; with the comment above it that says 'this is the line causing the error (`authentication.setAuthenticated(true);`)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You dont have to explicitly call `authentication.setAuthenticated(true)` (in fact, you are not allowed). The constructor does that for you.

You are, however, invoking the wrong constructor. You should be calling:

```
Authentication authentication 
    = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(tempUser, password, authorities);
```

Check the javadoc for UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.

Comment: Awesome! thanks very much.  Could I ask why both the `User` and `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` constructors need a list of grantedauthorities? Anyway it works so I'll accept this when I can

Comment: It's two levels of abstraction that happen to collide here. UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken is concrete version of a an entity that may or may not be authenticated (Authentication). A User is an implementation of a Principal (details of a user) existing independently of any authentication status.

Comment: Ran into same issue, assumed that I needed to explicitly call `setAuthenticated()` method.

Comment: So meaning after invoking 

Authentication authentication 
    = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(tempUser, password, authorities);

I can call authentication.isAuthenticated(), which is expected to return TRUE?

Comment: note that user and password should not be null, otherwise isAuthenticated will return false even after calling the constructor with correct authorities